# querySelector() attachEvent() not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button like bellow

```
<input type="button" value="check" />
```

And,I try to alert on this button click as follows

```
 document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').attachEvent('onclick', function() { alert(1); });
```

But this is not working,Why?

Comment: `attachEvent` only works on IE browsers! You are probably looking for the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

Comment: Go for `addEventListener` in case of browsers other than IE..`document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', function() { alert(1); }); `

Comment: why not work with jQuery

Comment: @OliSoproniB. Just for study purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code snippet:-

```
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', function() { alert(1); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ones help:

link: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_addeventlistener_crossbrowser

doc: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp